# Get Nearby Restaurants with delivery radius of the restaurant (like UberEats and Zomato)

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to get the restaurants that comes inside the user’s co-ordinate.
Each of the restaurants has its own co-ordinate with a varying delivery radius.

I am new to mongodb but i tried the $nearBy query, but it requires the max-distance parameter.

So we will have only user’s co-ordinate supplied to the query and query will try to see which of the restaurants are qualified for the user’s co-ordinate according to restaurant’s delivery radius.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think that the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/) may serve you better with explanations and photos